# Flash Actionscript 3 passing a number to dynamic text field

Tags: actionscript-3

On my stage I have a dynamic text field (instance name = lives).

In my actionscript I have created a number variable called livesnum. And then beneath that I'm setting the textfields value to be the livesnum variable but I get the following error:

```
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type String.
```

My actionscript is as follows :

```
var livesnum:Number = 4; //Amount of lives

lives.text = livesnum;
```

How would I achieve setting the textfield as the numeric value of the variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `toString`() function:

```
lives.text=livesnum.toString()
```

or use a cast `String()`:

```
lives.text=String(livesnum);
```